# URL params have not updated yet when we listent to history in react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a url listener in my component like this:

```
  this.urlListener = this.props.history.listen(location => {

      console.log(this.props.match.params.cityname);

    });
```

The problem is that when I update the URL, I want to access to new parameters. But, this.props.match.params still contains params with the old values.

My route URL is /a/:cityname

In console.log() I see past cityname, not the new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that react-router-dom matches the url and gives you parsed url based on params and search queries:

```
import { withRouter, matchPath } from "react-router-dom";

   let urlmatch = matchPath(location.pathname, {
        path: this.props.match.path
      });
```

So urlmatch contains new params.

BingO!

Comment: Perfect. I've looked through maybe 10+ answers on how to handle the back button but they all miss this key part.  [matchPath](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/matchPath)